# reinterpret_cast to the same type

Tags: c++, c++14, standards, reinterpret-cast

Consider following program:

```cpp
struct A{};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b = a;
    A c = reinterpret_cast<A>(a);
}
```

The compiler(g++14) throws an error about `invalid cast from type 'A' to type 'A'`.
Why is casting to the same type invalid?

Comment: This is a useful question, as I also wanted to do this for a particular reason:   When working around issues with an older compiler not supporting `if constexpr`, this allowed a mechanism for dummy casting an object (reference) to its own known type in a templated expression, so that would still compile without a lot of additional messy SFINAE-enabled helper functions added.

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed, because the standard says so.

There is a rather limited set of allowed conversion that you can do with `reinterpret_cast`. See eg [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). For example the first point listed there is:

> 1) An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or
>   pointer-to-member type can be converted to its own type. The resulting
>   value is the same as the value of expression. (since C++11)

However, casting a custom type (no pointer!) to itself is not on the list. Why would you do that anyhow?

Comment: See also [expr.reinterpret.cast](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast). Do you know why it's allowed to cast the listed types to itself then?

Comment: @lubgr thats an interesting question, i'd guess that something else in c++11 required to add that feature, because on its own it looks rather useless

Comment: @lubgr ping me if you open one. `reinterpret_cast` is a constant source of confusion for me, one of the topics I guess I never stop learning new stuff

Comment: Ping... here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58446304/9593596).

Comment: From the cited sample (cppreference), it sounds exactly like `int a; reinterpret_cast<int>(a);` should be permitted. However, Programiz's C++ compiler doesn't seem to allow it when compiling.

Comment: @Stev `int a; reinterpret_cast<int>(a);` gets compiled without any issues when I try on Programiz. If you get an error you can open a question with more information. Without the compiler error message there is not much one can do to help

Answer (score 3):

Because `reinterpret_cast` cannot be used for classes and structures, it should be used to reinterpret pointers, references and integral types. It is very well explained in [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

So, in your case one possible valid expression would be `reinterpret_cast<A*>(&a)`

Comment: Or `reinterpret_cast<A&>(a);`

Answer (score 3):

reinterpret_cast should be used to pointers, references and integral types.

I don't know, Why someone do that.

But Still you want do.You can do like.

```
 A *d = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&a);
```

or

```
A c = reinterpret_cast<A&>(a);
```