# Why is it allowed to reinterpret_cast integral, enumeration and pointer-to-member types to themselves?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

In [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58429179/9593596), we saw that it's not allowed to `reinterpret_cast` some custom class type instance to itself; `struct A{}; reinterpret_cast<A>(A{});` is invalid (it works only through references or pointers). Which seems to make sense, because of the lack of real-world scenarios where such identity conversion is necessary.

Checking the corresponding standard clause, we have in [[expr.reinterpret.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast) (emphasis mine):

> 1 [...] Conversions that can be performed explicitly using `reinterpret_­cast` are listed below.
>   No other conversion can be performed explicitly using `reinterpret_­cast`.
>
> 2 [...] **An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be explicitly converted to its own type**; such a cast yields the value of its operand.

So `reinterpret_cast<int>(42)` is allowed, while the same cast with a `struct A{}` is not. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was part of resolving [DR 799](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#799). The issue was as follows:

> The note in 8.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast] paragraph 2 says,
>
> > Subject to the restrictions in this section, an expression may be cast
> >     to its own type using a reinterpret_cast operator.
>
> However, there is nothing in the normative text that permits this conversion, and
>   paragraph 1 forbids any conversion not explicitly permitted.

The idea in the note was deemed worthwhile, that `reinterpret_cast` should be allowed to do the identity conversion. So the normative text you ask about was added. I can assume the restriction to some fundamental types is a cautious first (and maybe even only) step. Since it doesn't open the can of worms associated with class types and the need to call their constructors. `reinterpret_cast` is all about not creating new objects, and one can do that with fundamental types. Not sure the same applies to class types.

Comment: "The idea in the note was deemed worthwhile, that reinterpret_cast should be allowed to do the identity conversion.". Why? And I feel that the explanation at DR 799 is a little bit incorrect: "However, there is nothing in the normative text that permits this conversion, and paragraph 1 forbids any conversion not explicitly permitted". You can cast a pointer to its own type, for example. There is no explanation at 799, why they changed the text to allowing integral/enum/pointer identity conversion.

Comment: @geza - I don't have the minutes. All I can do is present my attempt at explain the rationale, which I have.